# iPhone apps for company-internal use - possible?

Tags: iphone

I hope this is still programming related, as SuperUser doesn't seem the appropriate place.

Basically I wonder if it is possible to have Applications that are internal to a company on the iPhone? That is something like a companion Application to an Intranet (when Safari and Mail just don't cut it) which wouldn't make sense on the AppStore (and likely wouldn't get approved anyway).

Is something like that possible (without Jailbreaking or doing anything else that Apple doesn't normally want)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 types of subscription for the iPhone developer:

- $99 a year - [regular program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/) with the ability to upload your applications to the app store.
- $299 a year - [enterprise program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/) that is used for distributing apps inside the company...

The second program is exactly for you.

Comment: Note that you need to be a biggish company (500+ employees) to qualify for the enterprise program. On the other hand, if you're talking about less than 100 users, you might be able to make do with [ad hoc distribution](http://developer.apple.com/programs/iphone/distribute.html).

Comment: @walkytalky nice tip, the ad-hoc solution!

Answer (score 2):

There's the [Iphone enterprise deployment program](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/Enterprise_Deployment_Guide.pdf). It seems to cover exactly the scenario you are describing, although I am not sure about the admission criteria you have fulfill.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so i think the best bet is to develop a web application and develop a custom skin so that it can be viewed properly in the iphone web browser safari, they could then add a shortcut to the webapp to their home screen add a fancy icon to it and then it would look like a iPhone app.