# Develop iPhone application within a company?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone apps for company-internal use - possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032031/iphone-apps-for-company-internal-use-possible)

As a developer, I can sign up with Apple to develop and sell applications through Apple store. I think there may be ways for companies to setup company-wide applications so that those applications can only be deployed, downloaded, updated and used within a company. Is that true?

If so, does any one have experience to develop application within a company for iPhone? What's the procedure? Is it possible to set up a company Store for deploying and using applications? If there is any price related to this kind of service? and how much if it is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct, there's an [iPhone developer program for enterprises](http://developer.apple.com/programs/iphone/enterprise/).

Answer (score 1):

this link should get you started: http://www.apple.com/iphone/business/

Actually there's a special [enterprise development program](http://developer.apple.com/support/iphone/enrollment.html), which costs $299 per year. It allows in-house development.

Answer (score -1):

I have answered for a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032031/iphone-apps-for-company-internal-use-possible/3032124#3032124). Here's my post again, below:

"You have 2 types of subscription for the iPhone developer:

$99 a year - regular program with the ability to upload your applications to the app store.
$299 a year - enterprise program that is used for distributing apps inside the company...
The second program is exactly for you."

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Manitoba, I have linked to an answer where there is a full explanation with links to the programs. It should answer the question.